Multiplication of matrix by submatrices
I have a $J \times J$ matrix $C$ that is upper triangular. Also, $C'C$ is positive definite. I also have a matrix $A$ formed by submatrices of size $J \times K$ as follows $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3 \\ \vdots \\ A_N \end{bmatrix}$,
where $A_i = [I_{J \times J}\  B_{i_{J \times (K - J)}}]$ for each $i$. I create a new matrix $A_{\text{new}}$ such that
$A_{\text{new}} = \begin{bmatrix} CA_1 \\ CA_2 \\ CA_3 \\ \vdots \\ CA_N \end{bmatrix}$.
Notice that $A_{\text{new}}$ can be written as $A_{\text{new}} = \begin{bmatrix} C & CB_1 \\ C & CB_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ C & CB_N \end{bmatrix}$.
Is there a way for me to write $A_{\text{new}}'*A_{\text{new}}$ in terms of matrix operations or concatenations?
I am working on a loop where on each iteration I need to obtain a matrix $A_{\text{new}}(C)$ for a different value of $C$. This is extremely costly computationally as the matrices $_$ and $C$ are huge, so any suggestions on an easy way to make these computations for a given $C$ is appreciated!
Thank you!
